# How are folks using the EventLogFile records?

Tags: lightning, architecture

This is a very general question but my company is just looking into ways to start using the Lightning Interaction Event data (EventLogFile) to establish a better insight into what users are interacting with on a daily/weekly basis. Some initial scenarios we're thinking are:

- Check if the user needs to retain expensive licenses or if they can be removed
- See if functionality is no longer being used and use data in discussions with stakeholders

My general question is what general ways have folks used this data in their organisations and what way are you driving value from it? It's ALOT of data so we want to make sure we're working smarter to get some value out of it.